# Problems while merging two pandas dataframes with different shapes?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

This is quite simple, but I do not get why I can't merge two dataframes. I have the following `df`s with different shapes (one is larger and wider than the other):

df1

```
    A                      id
0   microsoft inc          1
1   apple computer.        2
2   Google Inc.            3
3   IBM                    4
4   amazon, Inc.           5
```

df2

```
    B   C   D   E   id
0   (01780-500-01)  237489 - 342    API     True.   1
0   (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
0   23423423    API     NaN     NaN     3
0   (001722-5e240-60)   NaN     NaN     Other   4
1   (0012172-52411-60)  32423423.   NaN     Other   4
0   29849032-29482390   API     Yes     False   5
1   329482030-23490-1   API     Yes     False   5
```

I would like to merge `df1` and `df2` by the `index` column:

df3

```
    A   B   C   D   E   id
0   microsoft inc   (01780-500-01)  237489 - 342    API     True.   1
1   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
2   Google Inc. 23423423    API     NaN     NaN     3
3   IBM (001722-5e240-60)   NaN     NaN     Other   4
4   IBM (0012172-52411-60)  32423423.   NaN     Other   4
5   amazon, Inc.    29849032-29482390   API     Yes     False   5
6   amazon, Inc.    329482030-23490-1   API     Yes     False   5
```

I know that this could be done by using [merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). Also, I read this excellent [tutorial](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_join_merge_dataframe.html) and tried to:

In:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df1.id, how='outer')
```

Out:

```
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Then I tried:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, on='id', how='outer')
```

And apparently its repeating several times the merged rows, something like this:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   index
0   microsoft inc   (01780-500-01)  237489 - 342    API     True.   1
1   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
2   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
3   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
4   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
5   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
6   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
7   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
8   apple computer. (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
...
```

I think that this is related with the fact that I created a temporal index `df2['position'] = df2.index` since the indices look weird, and then removed it. So, my question is how to get `df3`?

**UPDATE**

I fixed the index of `df2` like this:

```
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

And now looks like this:

```
    B   C   D   E   id
0   (01780-500-01)  237489 - 342    API     True.   1
1   (409-6043-01)   234324  API     Other   2
2   23423423    API     NaN     NaN     3
3   (001722-5e240-60)   NaN     NaN     Other   4
4   (0012172-52411-60)  32423423.   NaN     Other   4
5   29849032-29482390   API     Yes     False   5
6   329482030-23490-1   API     Yes     False   5
```

I am still having the same issue. The merged rows are repeating several times.

```
>>>print(df2.dtypes)
B    object
C    object
D    object
E    object
id   int64
dtype: object

>>>print(df1.dtypes)
A                object
id               int64
dtype: object
```

**Update2**

```
>>>print(df2['id'])
0        1
1        2
2        3
3        4
4        4
5        5
6        5
7        6
8        6
9        7
10       8
11       8
12       8
13       8
14       9
15      10
16      11
17      11
18      12
19      12
20      13
21      13
22      14
23      15
24      16
25      16
26      17
27      17
28      18
29      18
      ... 
476    132
477    132
478    132
479    132
480    132
481    132
482    132
483    132
484    133
485    133
486    133
487    133
488    134
489    134
490    134
491    134
492    135
493    135
494    136
495    136
496    137
497    137
498    137
499    137
500    137
501    137
502    137
503    138
504    138
505    138
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

And

```
>>>print(df1)

0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
8       9
9      10
10     11
11      8
12     12
13      6
14      7
15      8
16      6
17     11
18     13
19     14
20     15
21     11
22      2
23     16
24     17
25     18
26      9
27     19
28     11
29     20
       ..
108    57
109    43
110    22
111     2
112    58
113    49
114    22
115    59
116     2
117     6
118    22
119     2
120    37
121     2
122     9
123    60
124    61
125    62
126    63
127    42
128    64
129     4
130    29
131    11
132     2
133    25
134     4
135    65
136    66
137     4
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @JohnE, I also tried that one and the same behavior...it is repeating several times the merged rows. Is there any way I can clarify the question?.

Comment: I just tried and it works fine for me.  I suspect you don't have the data read in correctly for df2 (see how your columns don't line up?).  Double check that if you type `df['id']` that it contains what you think it does.

Comment: If you are trying to merge on a common index axis, I would recommend using [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) instead. Try and see if you do get the correct results. But make sure, both the index axis are set appropriately.

Comment: True, but it appears he is trying to join on 'id', not the index.  But setting index to 'id' for each one and then using `join` would also be a good way to  approach this.

Comment: Thanks @NickilMaveli, is there any way to fix the index in df2?.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, could you provide an example for this case using join?.

Comment: @JohnE, I added the detail you where looking!.

Comment: @johndoe, figured it out. You have duplicates in `df1.id`. Since you're mapping a company to an id, I would imagine that the mapping is unique. I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the index as `id` and then using `join`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('microsoft inc',1),
('apple computer.',2),
('Google Inc.',3),
('IBM',4),
('amazon, Inc.',5)],columns = ('A','id'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([('(01780-500-01)','237489', '- 342','API',   1),
('(409-6043-01)','234324', ' API','Other   ',2),
('23423423','API', 'NaN','NaN',     3),
('(001722-5e240-60)','NaN', 'NaN','Other',   4),
('(0012172-52411-60)','32423423','   NaN','Other',   4),
('29849032-29482390','API', '    Yes','     False',   5),
('329482030-23490-1','API', '    Yes','     False',   5)],
columns = ['B','C','D','E','id'])

df1  =df1.set_index('id')
df1.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df2  = df2.set_index('id')
df3  = df1.join(df2,how='outer')
```

Since you've set the index columns (aka join keys) for both dataframes, you wouldn't have to specify the `on='id'` param.

This is an alternate way to solve the problem.. I don't see anything wrong with `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='outer')`. You might want to double check the `id` column in both dataframes, as mentioned by @JohnE

Comment: Yeah, actually inner vs outer is irrelevant here since 'id' ranges from 1 to 5 (inclusive) for both datasets.

Comment: What's the output of `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtypes`?

Comment: I spoted the problem... check the `id`s of `df1` it is not unique!.... I did :  `df['id'] = df.index + 1` in order to force them  to be unique. Your solution is actually right!. The problem is that is leaving a blank `id` row below the columns.. How can I remove it?.

Comment: How can I remove the id blank row?.

Comment: The blank `id` row below the column is just a named index, it's nothing to worry about. If you want to get rid of it just do `df3 = df3.reset_index()` at the end :) Also - I would recommend `df1.drop_duplicates()` over `df1['id'] = df1.index + 1` - assuming that the df1 and df2 use `id` as the join key. It's unsafe to arithmetically change the join key, you could get incorrect results!